# Delete rows from multiple tables with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables

1. `userTable` with following rows `Id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`
2. `Product A` with following rows `Id`, `UserId`(FK), `startDate`
3. `Product D` with following rows `Id`, `UserId`(FK), `startDate`

I want to delete rows from three tables with particular UserId.

What I want to achieve -

1. Find the id given email `(select id from userTable where Email = 'abc.com')` - got back id - 3
2. `Delete from Product A where id = 3`
3. `Delete from Product D where id = 3`
4. `Delete from userTable where id = 3`

I want to create a script.

Any help is appreciated or learning reference would be great.

Comment: If I understand right (I would be a numb nut if I didn't), UserId in Product A/D is FK to Id in table userTable, right?

Comment: @LudvigRydahl that's correct!

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable and save the `id` to that variable. Use that `Id` for the delete query.

```
DECLARE @Id INT;

SELECT @Id=id 
FROM userTable 
WHERE Email = 'abc.com'

DELETE FROM Product A WHERE id = @Id
DELETE FROM Product D WHERE id = @Id
DELETE FROM userTable WHERE id = @Id
```

But I guess in your case you have `UserId` as the FK so you should be trying this:

```
DELETE FROM Product A WHERE UserId= @Id
DELETE FROM Product D WHERE UserId= @Id
DELETE FROM userTable WHERE id = @Id
```

**Note:** If you want to do the same thing what's there in question, go for 1st one. If you want to delete the relevant user records from `A` and `D` table then go for the 2nd method where you are deleting the records using the FK.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your question you want something like this:

```
DELETE FROM
    userTable,
    ProductA,
    ProductB
WHERE
    userTable.Id = (select Id from userTable where Email like 'abc.com') AND
    userTable.Id = ProductA.Id AND
    userTable.Id = ProductB.Id;
```

And the Email in the subquery in the `WHERE` clause would be your input parameter

DISCLAIMER: From a Sybase/SQL Anywhere background, this would be possible, I'm not sure if it could be done in SQL-server.